# Finding source of memory leak in material-ui application

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

A super simple class object (along with many more complicated components across the app) appears to have a memory leak that I can't understand. I'm attaching a Material-UI `Menu` component to an `IconButton` component. Code below:

```js
import { theme } from '../custom_styles'

class VolumeControl extends React.PureComponent{
  state={
    open:false,
  }
  
  open_mute_menu = () => {
    this.setState({open:true})
  }

  close_mute_menu = () => {
    this.setState({open:false})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <IconButton onClick={this.open_mute_menu}>
          <VolumeUpIcon/>
        </IconButton>
        <Menu
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.close_mute_menu}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={this.close_mute_menu}>Menu Item 1</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.close_mute_menu}>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.close_mute_menu}>Menu Item 3</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.close_mute_menu}>Menu Item 4</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.close_mute_menu}>Menu Item 5</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

Clicking on the `IconButton` to open the `Menu` obviously increases the number of Dom Nodes as expected, but these are never garbage collected after closing the Menu. If I open the menu again the node count increases further. Each time I close and reopen the menu it increases again - so they're definitely not being garbage collected. I did think it was the anchor ref that might have killed (which I've removed above) but taking that out makes no difference.

I'm also using redux state store, which I also disabled and makes no difference.

Surely I've missed something horribly basic, but this is somewhat of a textbook example so is anyone able to shed some light on how this is still being referenced after it's unmounted?

I know that these are at fault as they appear in the heap snapshots as detached. But I just can't find the reason why.

Comment: To test if the menu is really the problem, you can try to
`{this.state.open && <Menu ... > ... </Menu>}` to force it to unmount.

Another thing that comes to mind is to inspect the html tree or using react dev tools https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi to inspect if there are multiple components being rendered.

Comment: Thanks @LucasP.Luiz. Are you able to clarify exactly how/where this code should be injected? I can't quite make out what you're suggesting

Comment: something like this: https://pastebin.com/HRYya1qf